# Ansible - How to manage Large list of small tasks

Tags: ansible, roles

I have written lots of small  yaml task files for an ansible project.
Only few of these tasks files are being reused (say 30%).
I wonder how to manage this big list of tasks, should I convert all of them to roles, and call the playbook with roles:
Playbook as below (pls ignore the syntaxe), will be clear,  **But I do not like to have a role for each simple task**.

```
- name: playbook with roles for each task
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - small_task_1
    - small_task_2
    - small_task_3
    - small_task_4
    ....
    ....
    - small_task_20
```

I liked the idea of putting them 2-3 roles, and call the task with include_task (or import_task), but the problem is, to each call of a task, I have to add "import_role: , name: , tasks_from" **EVEN THOUGH It's from the same role!**

$ ansible-galaxy role list
$ /home/user1/.ansible/roles

- roles_a, (unknown version)
- roles_b, (unknown version)

in roles_a and roles_b, I may have around 10 yaml tasks for each

,,,

- name: playbook with 2 roles
  hosts: all

  ```
  - name: small task 1
    include_role:
      name: role_a
      tasks_from: small_task_1

  - name: small task 2
    include_role:
      name: role_a
      tasks_from: small_task_2

  ......
  ......

  - name: small task 9
    include_role:
      name: role_a
      tasks_from: small_task_9

  - name: small task 10
    include_role:
      name: role_a
      tasks_from: small_task_10
  ```

,,,

Above thing is not very handy...

I would like to group the tasks in a "role" (or any other ansible thing), and call the tasks from that group... something like :

,,,

- name: playbook with 2 roles
  hosts: all

  ```
  - name: small tasks
    include_role:
      name: role_a
      tasks_from: small_task_1
      tasks_from: small_task_2

  ......
  ......

      tasks_from: small_task_9
      tasks_from: small_task_10
  ```

,,,

I've tried with block , but it does not shorten the playbook.

Can anyone guide me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your final example, you can just use a `loop` directive on your `include_role` task, like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: role_a
        tasks_from: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - small_task_1
        - small_task_2
        - small_task_3
        - small_task_4
```

Comment: Right! Thanks @larsks, will implement this.